# Authenticating a Node.js server for Twitter API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter, oauth

I have a node (express) server running locally and am attempting to send a GET request to the Twitter [/trends/place](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place) endpoint. I am using [this twitter NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) to facilitate. My understanding is I've gotten the correct consumer key, consumer secret, access token, and access token secret plugged into the API. I generated them on the dev.twitter website for my app.

Currently I am getting a `code: 32 message: 'Could not authenticate you.` error. I have tried with and without the parameters `{id: 1}` object. I have tested the curl statement generated with the Twitter oauth generator (see link 1) and it was successful. I have confirmed the four keys are all exporting properly from `creds.js` and importing properly into `server.js` with console logs.  Am I not understanding this NPM package properly?

Code below, minus front end and irrelevant handling:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var twitterAPI = require('twitter');
//just storing these as plaintext, pulled straight off the oath 
//twitter tool
var secrets = require(__dirname + '/creds.js');


var twitter = new twitterAPI({
  consumerKey: secrets.consumerKey,
  consumerSecret: secrets.consumerSecret,
  access_token_key: secrets.accessToken,
  access_token_secrets: secrets.accessTokenSecret
});


//send a get request to trends/place
twitter.get('trends/place', {id: 1}, function(error, tweets, response){
  console.log('myerror is: ', error);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('test');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log("Prompter listening on port 3000.");
});
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "twitter": "^1.2.5"
  }
}
```

I've `console.log()`'d the response object, and the headers on it are:

```
GET /1.1/trends/place.json?id=1 HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: node-twitter/1.2.5\r\nhost: api.twitter.com\r\nAuthorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="null",oauth_nonce="(hidden for stackoverflow)",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1459220083",oauth_token="(hidden for stackoverflow)",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="(hidden for stack overflow)"\r\ncontent-length: 0\r\n\r\n',
```

So that you don't have to scroll right a bunch, the interesting bit is:

`oauth_consumer_key="null"`

Why would that be null and all else getting through proper?

Comment: Years later, I get the same issue... request works in postman, but when I tried using the twitter npm package, I get the same exact issue - oauth_consumer_key is null in the Authorization request headers.  Did you ever figure this out?